# data loading - app launching on tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i encounter an issue with my application.

On one hand when my app launches, the first view displayed is a tableview within a tableviewcontroller.

On the other hand my app calls a web service to collect data. These methods are in MyAppDelegate\applicationDidFinishLaunching.

The thing is that my tableview is made of custom cells that need data from the web service.

I noticed that the view (with the tableview) is launched first and then MyAppDelegate\applicationDidFinishLaunchin is executed.

As a result the labels of my custom cells are all equal to null as my arrays aren't filled yet by the web service.

I would like to know the proper way to make it.

If anyone has an idea please tell me.

Wallou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSNotificationCenter to communicate to your UITableViewController that it needs to reloadData for the table.

To Register (in your UITableViewController.viewDidLoad):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(dataLoaded:)
    name:@"myapp.dataloaded" object:nil];

- (void)dataLoaded:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.table reloadData];
}
```

To post notifications (after you loaded the data):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:@"myapp.dataloaded" object:nil];
```

Comment: thx for the reply.
its my first iphone app.
I've read over the NSNOtificationCenter many times but never had to use it.
Can you help me a bit in implementing it in my code ?? I'm a bit lost (i.e where to do what?)

thx again